# TestNG reporting

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng, reporting

I want to Email my TestNG report to other users as well but when they are clicking on the screenshot link. They are not able to see the screenshot as it is stored in my local machine.

```
 String SaveandReturn =  ScreenShot.takeScreenShot("SaveAndReturnverification");
  Reporter.log("<a href=\"" + SaveandReturn + "\"><p align=\"left\"> Add Sub Service in LFA Services  screenshot at " + new Date()+ "</p>");
```

}

How can I attach the screenshot so that other people can also view the report.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to implement the following it would be quite useful if you have a lot of people who need to see the results of the tests at a given time, its what I have implemented in my enviornment.

I have created a web server using XAMPP. I then created a web page which has links to all the TestNG reports.

Might not suit your environment but its a good solution if it does.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for Extentreports which has good UI when compared to TestNG. it is an extended version of testNG reporting framework.

It also suits your requirement of sending the screenshots by keeping at local if you have hosted in your local machine using MongoDB.